# Retornar contenido JSONArray desde un servicio en Angular

Tags: angular

Estoy intentando incluir una Api Rest en mi proyecto de Angular, mi objetivo, es que desde una aplicación Android se llame a una URL desde el servidor y que este responda inmediatamente con un JsonArray.

He creado un servicio y hago pruebas llamando a ngOnInit() desde el componente principal, que a su vez llama a getListProducts(); y muestra correctamente el JsonArray por consola al momento de recargar la vista.

Desde este punto no sé como seguir, mi duda es como retornar esos datos, ya que solo los muestro por consola. También e intentado utilizar Api Tester o Postman para hacer pruebas, pero en el body me retorna el contenido HTML de la vista.

En resumen, esto es exactamente lo que quiero, llamar a una URL y responda con un JSONArray: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Dejo mi Componente y Servicio:

**App.Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataApiService } from 'src/app/services/data-api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private rest: DataApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.getListProducts();
  }

   getListProducts(){
     this.rest.getAllProducts().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
   }
 }
```

**Servicio:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DataApiService {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   getAllProducts(){
      const localUrl = 'assets/data/smartphone.json';
      return this.http.get(localUrl);
   }
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta es un tanto confusa, Ya tienes el servicio por asi decirlo el cual te deja acceder al JSON que seria este https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts segundo ya tienes un metodo que lo consume el cual es tu metodo en el Anuglar , ahora quieres mostrarlo en html ? o quieres consumir ese JSON desde otra parte ?

Answer (score 0):

lo que estas intentando hacer no es posible. Angular es un framework que se ejecuta del lado cliente. Tú quieres hacer un API REST y necesitas usar un lenguaje que se ejecute en el lado Servidor. Utiliza Node, PHP, Java ... para hacer este api. Te dejo por aquí un articulo que te lo explicara mejor que yo, un saludo.

https://medium.com/@federicojordn/simplertapp-estructura-b%C3%A1sica-de-una-api-rest-en-node-js-64b4c413c85c